# How do I trigger a message in Discord.net without responding to a command or event?

Tags: c#, discord.net

I just started learning how to make a Discord bot, and while making commands is easy enough I can't figure out how to make things happen without it being triggered externally. All the examples of this I found seemed to be using outdated versions of Discord.net, or they never actually got an answer.

I'm using [this template](https://github.com/Directoire/Discord.NET-Template) to get up and running, since I don't have the skill to make a bot from scratch.

Edit: I decided to not use the template, instead using the example from the Discord.net repo. In case anyone else has this issue and is also not smart, you can get a reference to a channel in a server by calling GetChannel on the client object, which you'll need a reference to. Be sure to have it in OnReady so the bot has access to the server data.

Comment: This is from the [Discord.Net docs](https://docs.stillu.cc/faq/basics/basic-operations.html#how-do-i-send-a-message)

Comment: Thanks, turns out I didn't know how to get a reference to the client object. Got it figured out now.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.